# Drupal 8 breadcrumb and books

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I have taxonomy term with name "Category" and url:

```
category
```

I have created simple page "test" with this tag, and url for that page is:

```
/category/test
```

because there is prefix with /category path, breadcrumb shows:

```
Home / Category
```

Category is linked to taxonomy term. Works like a charm. Problem is when I create book from this page. Category tag just disappear from breadcrump. How i can keep my breadcrumb based on path of taxonomy term for books?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module.

With this module, you can automatically provide a URL path for a specific content type, with tokens. For your books, it could looks like this :

```
[node:field_book_category:entity:name]/[node:title]
```

where field_book_category is the machine name of the field you use to link your taxonomy "Category" to your books.

Comment: its not the problem. Im using it already. Problem is that breadcrumb dont work when i change node to book.